# PostGis Erro invalid geometry

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm using `POSTGIS="2.4"` and `Postgresql 9.6`  and facing following error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCUCD.gif]

While trying to insert polygon data

> INSERT INTO aalis.mv_l1_parcelownership_aalis (geometry) VALUES
>   (st_Polygonfromtext ('polygon(482449.20552234241,
>   999758.79058533313,.....)',20137));

Answer (score 4):

You're close :-)

The geometry you provided in your insert statement is invalid. Make sure that your `POLYGONS` are really correct and try one of these statements (using [`ST_GeomFromText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) or [`ST_PolygonFromText`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PolygonFromText.html)):

```
INSERT INTO aalis.mv_l1_parcelownership_aalis 
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))',20137));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO aalis.mv_l1_parcelownership_aalis 
VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))',20137));
```

To check if your geometries are correct you can use [`ST_IsValid`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html):

```
SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 1 2, 1 1, 0 0))'));
HINWEIS:  Self-intersection at or near point 0 0
 st_isvalid 
------------
 f
(1 Zeile)

SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'));
 st_isvalid 
------------
 t
(1 Zeile)
```

Keep in mind also that the [`WKT`](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wkt-crs) standard sort of expects double parenthesis `((` for polygons with 0 interior rings, and yours has only one: `'polygon(482449.20552234241, 999758.79058533313,.....)`. Also, the *x* and *y* axes are separated by space, *not* by comma. Commas separate coordinate pairs instead.

Example:

```
SELECT ST_IsValid('POLYGON((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))');
 st_isvalid 
------------
 t
(1 Zeile)

SELECT ST_IsValid('POLYGON(30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10)');

FEHLER:  parse error - invalid geometry
ZEILE 1: SELECT ST_IsValid('POLYGON(30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10...
                           ^
TIP:  "POLYGON(30 " <-- parse error at position 11 within geometry
```

Answer (score 2):

Your polygon text is way off, and includes the characters `.....`, which are not valid:

```
polygon(482449.20552234241, 999758.79058533313,.....)
```

Not sure what your coordinates are, but the polygon text is generally in the form:

```
polygon((1.000 1.000, 2.000 1.500, 3.000 2.000, 1.000 1.000))
```

Note that the x-y pairs are in the form `x y`, and there are commas between the pairs.

Comment: i used the dots just as etc because the text is too long  any ways it works. the commas and brackets was causing me errors. Thanks all :)